# R For Loop Adding Columns to Data Frame - Last Column Only

Tags: r

I'm a little new to R coming from SAS and all I'm trying to do is to compute some variables from a set of variables labeled mean1-meanN where N=numclust in the code below.  I can do this blindfolded in SAS, but after several days and extensive searching and researching and trying and retrying, I conceed.  I need help!

Here is the full code:

```
IndiceCalc<-function(filePath,numclust){


  #convert appropriate SAS checkerboard file to R

  fileName <-     paste(filePath,"\\","checkerboard",numclust,".sas7bdat",sep="")
  fromSAS<-read.sas7bdat(file=fileName)


  #keep relevant columns and subset

  meanVars<-paste("mean",1:numclust,sep="")
  vars2keep<-c("groupnum","GroupName","variable","label",meanVars)
  sub.fromSAS<-na.omit(subset(fromSAS,totalmean!=0,select=vars2keep))

  #calculate indices across segment rows

  output<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=numclust,nrow=nrow(sub.fromSAS)))

  for (i in 1:numclust){

    j=numclust+4
    output[,i]<-(sub.fromSAS[,j]-rowAvgs(sub.fromSAS[,meanVars],        na.rm=TRUE))/rowStdevs(sub.fromSAS[,meanVars], na.rm=TRUE)
  }


  colnames(output)<-paste("index",1:numclust,sep="")

  calcDat<-cbind(sub.fromSAS,output)

  head(calcDat)

}
```

I attempted the approach recommended by many, by creating a blank dataframe/matrix and filling it in, then cbinding it to my original dataframe.

I do get a dataframe back with my original data plus the columns Index1-IndexN.  However, the data populated is all from the result of the N'th column/iteration.

```
index1  index2  index3  index4  index5
-0.9384286  -0.9384286  -0.9384286  -0.9384286  -0.9384286
0.481684    0.481684    0.481684    0.481684    0.481684
0.3883754   0.3883754   0.3883754   0.3883754   0.3883754
0.645928    0.645928    0.645928    0.645928    0.645928
1.6327587   1.6327587   1.6327587   1.6327587   1.6327587
-0.3524674  -0.3524674  -0.3524674  -0.3524674  -0.3524674
```

Not sure how I can fix this.  Help!

Comment: Fyi, `paste(...,sep="")` has `paste0(...)` as a shortcut.

Comment: Can you post minimally useful input data that can be used to reproduce what you have?

Comment: `j=numclust+4`? Shouldn't it be `j=i+4`? You are taking always the same column each iteration.

Comment: nicola!!!  THANKS!!!!!!!!!  That was it!!!!  I knew it had to be something simple after looking at this for several hours...

Comment: Frank, thanks for the shortcut.

Comment: Something like `mDF = sub.fromSAS[,meanVars]; sub.fromSAS[,paste("index",1:numclust,sep="")] <- (sub.fromSAS-rowMeans(mDF,na.rm=TRUE))/rowSds(mDF)` where rowSds comes from the MatrixStats package, I guess. You might also want to look at `?scale`.

Comment: Thanks, Frank -- I initially went that route of directly adding to my existing dataframe to no avail.  FYI, the rowStdevs came from the fBasics package

Comment: As someone who has to use `SAS` for work but can use `R`, once you get over the learning curve you will never look back! `R` is so much better. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is something that I would not do in R if I had the choice, here is a snippet that would do what you want after you obtain your `sub.fromSAS`:

```
calcDat <- cbind( # bind to the original dataframe
  sub.fromSAS
  , t( # transpose the matrix to get back into original orientation
    # Apply code of anonymous function row-wise
    # on the sub-dataframe with meanX... columns
    apply(sub.fromSAS[, 4+1:numclust] , 1, function(x) {

      # Change the name of columns from meanX to indexX
      names(x) <- paste0("index", 1:numclust)

      # Compute Z scores 
      (x - mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)) / sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    )))
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still getting accustomed to transitioning from SAS to R and avoiding using the apply set of functions as opposed to looping.  The code above worked out nicely!